# My son keeps saying he's hearing his name in ambient sounds..?

Tags: pre-teen, psychology

So my 11 year old has been saying lately that he keeps hearing his name in ambient noises. It seems to be primarily in the breeze, or rustling leaves, or the rain. After some thought I can (with a stretch of imagination) see how he could be hearing it. He has a simple 2 syllable name (Mason), so a simple shift in pitch *could* be interpreted that way?

E.g. "SHH-shh". The "s" in his name is the loudest sound, so it's understandable.

However, is this normal? Particularly because it's only ever *his* name, regardless of the time of day, not just "scary sounds" at bedtime in the dark. It can happen in the middle of the day during the rain, or on a windy day, or even something rolling through dried leaves.

Comment: While the answer given may correctly indicate the problem's nature, if it's an auditory phenomenon, it's in the realm of medicine. There are other medical conditions that can cause this. Start with his primary care provider and ask for a referral to the appropriate specialist(s). Thanks.

Comment: @anonagoodnurse, This question does not ask for medical advice, it asks about a behavior that's reported by a child,  which is parenting.  My answer,  being about a possible medical issue, does not invalidate the question.

Comment: @Cecilia - When behaviors might/are likely to have a medical reason, it becomes a medical advice issue. This is much different than, say, a child repeatedly chewing on electrical cords or sticking their fingers in sockets, which are unlikely to have a medical basis. The question is not invalid. It is simply closed, and will most likely remain so, but I'll run it by the other mods.

Comment: Hi Ben/Cecilia - yes, I'd have to agree with anongoodnurse here - this falls into our site closure category of "requires medical advice" and that cannot be done comprehensively on a Q&A site, despite Cecilia's good answer (which I have upvoted already)

Answer (score 2):

Your son may be expressing a real  phenomena created by his auditor system.  Below is a link to a foundation that works with children and adults that have auditory processing issues.   The link has a list of behaviors that can indicate an auditory processing disorder.

[Able Kids Foundation](https://www.ablekidsfoundation.org/central-auditory-processing-disorder-services/behaviors-associated-with-capd/)

The fact that your son hears his name when there's background noise,  like wind,  is consistent with a confused auditory system.

I would take a look at the list of behaviors, on your own,  and see if your observations of your son match.

Kids don't know what's not normal,  they just adjust to what is,  so your son may be having issues hearing that he has never spoken about. The questions below may help him talk about other hearing issues he may have.

1. do you ever find it hard to hear your teachers, friends,  team-mates, or coaches?
2. when it's noisy, can you hear what other people say to you?
3. do you hear sounds that you can't identify?

While your son's comments about hearing his name may seem odd, it could be that he has a diagnosable hearing issue, one that may or may not show up in a regular hearing test.

While there are steps you and others can take to do an initial evaluation, if there are any signs that your son has a Central Auditory Processing Disorder,  it's best to talk to the experts and get their input in how to proceed.